# spss python error stops the processor

Tags: spss

when i run spss.Submit, and the code has an error, I am not able to run a python block again in the same session.

for example:

```
begin program.
import spss
spss.Submit("GET  FILE='//covenas/decisionsupport/episodes.sav'.")
#*the next line causes an error because it is out of order.
spss.Submit("match files /table='//covenas/decisionsupport/rutable.sav' /file=* /by ru.")
spss.Submit("exe.")
end program.

begin program.
print '<code here>'
end program.
```

It looks normal, but when the processor starts the next block, the lower right corner says
'running begin program.'

but nothing ever happens again... until i shut down the engine.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

I also tried this

```
begin program.
import spss
try:
 spss.Submit("GET  FILE='//covenas/decisionsupport/episodes.sav'.")
 spss.Submit("select if primdx='295.70' and xdate.year(opdate)=2012.")
 spss.Submit("exe.")
 spss.Submit("sort cases by case.")
 spss.Submit("match files /table='//covenas/decisionsupport/rutable.sav' /file=* /by ru.")
 spss.Submit("exe.")
 spss.Submit("save outfile='//covenas\decisionsupport/aaaaa1.sav'.")
except Exception,e:
 print e
end program.
```

It feels like time to get rid of spss.

It's specifically a sort gone wrong that kills it.

this works fine

```
begin program.
not code
end program.

begin program.
print 'does it stop?'
end program.
```

Comment: You will probably want to change the match files syntax to `match files file = * /table='//covenas/decisionsupport/rutable.sav' /by ru`. The current way it is done it makes a new (unnamed) table, which then will be discarded if any other named dataset(s) exist because the table line is first. I would probably try *naming* the dataset and the making sure *it is the active dataset* before performing any other transformations. Can't speak specifically to the python error, it is too much of a pain to reproduce this exactly in its current form.

Comment: Also note `rutable.sav` needs to be sorted on `ru` for the match as well.

Comment: my problem is that when i have an error like this (not that i don't realize it is an error), i am not able to recover without closing spss.